# Angular2 How to write an effective method to highlight the active menu in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my application, the navbar has upto 2 levels of submenu.  My requirement is to change few features of a menu when either it is selected or any of its submenu (of any level) is selected.  I have been given this code that does it in an ineffective way till date (ie) writing one function for every  in navbar which will make all of its specific CSS/image changes.  But I would like to find an effective way (mostly one method) which will perform all the CSS changes when required data is provided as input.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wrapper zeroPadding">
<nav id="sidebar">
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="firstEmptyDiv">
            <div class="toggleBtnDiv" (click)="toggleBtn()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars toggleButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
                <img class="iconImg" id="iconImg" src="/assets/images/dashboard_icon.svg" alt="Dashboard menu icon" />
                <br>
                <span class="textWrap" *ngIf="buttonColor">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav nav-stacked" *ngIf="this.hasCompanyStructureAccess">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" [style.border-left]="borderColor"
                        [style.background-color]="color">
                    <img class="iconImg" id="iconImg" [src]="imgSrc" alt="Company structure menu icon" />
                    <span [style.color]="routerText" *ngIf="buttonColor" class="textWrap overflow-wrap">Company Structure</span>
                    <span [style.color]="caretColor" class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu slide">
                    <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewLocationAccess">
                        <a routerLink="/location" routerLinkActive="active">Location</a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewBranchAccess">
                        <a routerLink="/branch" routerLinkActive="active">Branch</a>
                    <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewRoleAccess">
                        <a routerLink="/role" routerLinkActive="active">Role</a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewDepartmentAccess">
                        <a routerLink="/department" routerLinkActive="active">Department</a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewDesignationAccess">
                        <a routerLink="/designation" routerLinkActive="active">Designation</a>                            
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf="!needToShowFlag">
                        <a routerLink="ACL" (click)="ACL()" routerLinkActive="active">ACL</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav nav-stacked">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" [style.border-left]="leaveModuleborderColor"
                        [style.background-color]="leaveModulecolor">
                    <img class="iconImg" [style.padding]="iconImgPadding" id="iconImg" [src]="leaveModuleSrc" alt="Leave menu icon" />
                    <span class="textWrap" [style.color]="leaveRouterText" *ngIf="buttonColor">Leave</span>
                    <span [style.color]="caretColorLeave" class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="submenuList" (click)="openSecondList()" (mouseover)="openSecondList()" [style.display]="submenuListDisplay">
                        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" id="leaveManagementlist">Configuration<span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="openSecondListFlag">
                            <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewGeneralConfigurationAccess">
                                <a tabindex="-1" routerLink="generalconfiguration" (click)="generalConfiguration()" routerLinkActive="active">General Configuration</a>
                            </li>
                            <li *ngIf="this.dataService.hasViewListLeaveAllocationAccess">
                                <a tabindex="-1" (click)="listLeaveAllocation()" routerLinkActive="active">Modify Leave Allocation</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="applyLeaveTab">
                        <a (click)="applyLeave()">Apply Leave</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11" id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In this code excerpt, when I select a submenu say 'Location', then its main menu 'Company Structure' should be changed with the following CSS values.

1) A different image should be loaded for this menu

2) background color to be changed

3) Color of caret symbol to be changed

4) A different colored border-left to be included

5) Background color of 'Location' submenu should be changed.

Similar CSS change should happen when clicking on 2 level submenu too like 'General configuration' in the example.

Any suggestions to come up with an effective way to meet this requirement is welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you inspected one of your links in Chrome?  You should notice how the class changes with "active" added when selected.  Write your CSS for these changes. e.g. li.nav-item.active>a.nav-link {
  font-weight: bold; color: purple;
}

Comment: yes Mathias, but my question is to know how to change the CSS values dynamically from Javascript, because each of my main menu item will have 2 images (1 to be shown when inactive and 1 to be shown when active); also no 2 menu item will have same images.  If I have to write it in CSS, then I cannot have common CSS to pick up the correct inactive image for each menu.  So, I'm looking for a method that will pick up the images, CSS values given for each menu and sub menu from a const and use it when that item becomes active.